# Nodejs Expressjs URI characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, uri, express, middleware

Is there a way to restrict allowed uri characters in Expressjs. like set a variable of characters:

```
allowed_uri_chars = 'a-zA-Z0-9'; etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most logical and easiest way to go would be to use a regex in some middleware:

```js
var url = require("url");

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  if(!pathname.match(/^[a-z0-9\/]+$/i)) return res.send(403);
  next();
});
```

Or, as the URL is already parsed by Express, but this is not exposed publicly, you may want to save one call to parse and rely on Express internals (which I wouldn't advise):

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req._parsedUrl.pathname.match(/^[a-z0-9\/]+$/i)) return res.send(403);
  next();
});
```

This ensures that your pathname (for `http://example.com/foo/bar?id=1334`, pathname would be `/foo/bar`) only contains letters, numbers, and slashes. It raises a 403 if not.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use a regex to parse the authorized chars?

Or do you mean in the routing directly?

Comment: Ok how would i go about using a regular expression? I really don't know anything about how to achieve this. I was thinking middleware to check the request. And want it done globally.